# Changing all countries names to English in Google Maps API Integration

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have a map that displays the world and a tool that allows people to add pins of Data to the map. However not all of the countries are in English. English country's are in English but Arabic countries are in Arabic, etc.

Have tried digging through the code but can't find where to update the language.

I want to change everything to display country in English. Here is the site: https://map.keepnaturewild.com

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('#map').length > 0)
  {
    if (document.querySelector('html').lang)
      lang = document.querySelector('html').lang;
    else
      lang = 'en';
```

You can try this in a js file. It allows you to choose the language of your map.

https://www.sitepoint.com/google-maps-javascript-api-the-right-way/